# Freeing Memory for QPushButtons with QMessageBox

Tags: c++, qt, memory, user-interface, destructor

I've instantiated a QMessageBox and added a couple of buttons to it like so:

```
QMessageBox message;
cancelButton = message.addButton(tr("Cancel"), QMessageBox::RejectRole);
okButton = message.addButton(tr("OK"), QMessageBox::ActionRole);
```

Is it necessary to call the destructors for each pushbutton before exiting, or does the QMessageBox destructor take care of everything?

Comment: I should hope you shouldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

When parent objects are deleted they delete their children.
So the buttons will be deleted when 'message' is.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still a bit unsure how these Qt objects manage memory. It's a bit more abstract than what I usually do.

Comment: Another answer disagrees with you. I'm not sure which to agree with.

Comment: @sj755 QMessageBox should delete the buttons itself. It has a buttonBox inside which will take ownership of the buttons you add to it.

Comment: Please see the first paragraph here: http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/objecttrees.html

Comment: @RA makes a good point. What I said is correct if the buttons are children of the parent widget, but if addButton() doesn't make the button a child then it won't apply.